# React strange internal issue depending on variable name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am having troubles with react depending on the name I give to a variable.

I am using eval sourcemap to see the generated code, and there is something I am not able to understand

I have 2 files. In one of them I export a HOC, and I import it in the other file.

In the same file where I export that HOC, I try to use it. This is the file where I have problems:

> File A: (DmDefEntity is my HOC)

```
class DmClass extends Component {
  ...
  ...
  methodA() {
    ...
    return <_internalDmClass def={entry.def} lbls={this.props.lbls[key]} path={key} name={key} />;
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}

const _internalDmClass = DmDefEntity(DmClass);
export default _internalDmClass;
```

The important lines transpiled show:

> Transpile with underscore in variable

```
  ...
  ...
  return _react3.default.createElement(_internalDmClass, { def: entry.def, lbls: this.props.lbls[key], path: key, name: key });
  ...
  ...

var _internalDmClass = (0, _DmDefEntity2.default)(DmClass);
exports.default = _internalDmClass;
```

Everything looks good here, and it actually works perfectly.

**However**

If i rename this variable into "internalDmClass" (with no underscore). My transpiled File becomes:

> Transpile with no underscore in variable

```
  ...
  ...
  return _react3.default.createElement('internalDmClass', { def: entry.def, lbls: this.props.lbls[key], path: key, name: key });
  ...
  ...

var internalDmClass = (0, _DmDefEntity2.default)(DmClass);
exports.default = internalDmClass;
```

**So** as you can see, depending on that underscore, it calls to createElement with a String, or the real HOC class, with its defaul property, etc.

The effect of this in execution time is the following error:

> Warning: Unknown props `def`, `lbls`, `path` on  tag. Remove these props from the element. For details, see https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/unknown-prop.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React, any component that starts with a lower case letter will be interpreted as an HTML element. To fix this, rename it to `InternalDmClass`.

> All lower case JSX tags will now be treated as HTML/SVG elements. They will no longer be treated as custom components in scope.
>
> [Source](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/f1f4ba40816e7d7848ad)

Answer (score 0):

As a temporal solution (I have not been able to understand yet how can the name of a variable affect this way) I have used the React.createElement function, instead of using jsx solution:

Have translated the

```
return <internalDmClass def={entry.def} lbls={this.props.lbls[key]} path={key} name={key} />;
```

into:

```
return React.createElement(internalDmClass, { def: entry.def, lbls: this.props.lbls[key], path: key, name: key });
```

Calling directly to this function, React seems not to need to translate the code. So its transpiled correctly.

I still would like to understand the issue.